Diarization with AWS streaming transcription
I have a problem with setting up diarization for AWS streaming transcription in reactjs.
I use @aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming.
I set the ShowSpeakerLabel to true, but when I log data.ShowSpeakerLabel, it shows undefined.
The transcription results show no Speaker key indicating the diarization.
Here is my code:
import * as awsTranscribeStreamingSdk from "@aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming";

const client = new awsTranscribeStreamingSdk.TranscribeStreamingClient({
  region: "xxxx",
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: "xxxx",
    secretAccessKey: "xxxx",
  },
});


export async function* startStreamTranscription({
  sampleRate,
  audioStream,
  shouldStop,
}: {
  sampleRate: number;
  audioStream: () => AsyncIterable<awsTranscribeStreamingSdk.AudioStream>;
  shouldStop: boolean;
}): AsyncGenerator<{
  isPartial?: boolean;
  content?: string;
}> {
  const params:awsTranscribeStreamingSdk.StartStreamTranscriptionCommandInput = {
    AudioStream: audioStream(),
    LanguageCode: awsTranscribeStreamingSdk.LanguageCode.EN_AU,
    MediaEncoding: awsTranscribeStreamingSdk.MediaEncoding.PCM,
    MediaSampleRateHertz: sampleRate,
    ShowSpeakerLabel: true,
  };

  const command = new awsTranscribeStreamingSdk.StartStreamTranscriptionCommand(params);
  const data = await client.send(command)

  // something else

I read the aws documentation, read the aws-sdk/client-transcribe-streaming source code, but it seems that the only thing I can do is assigning ShowSpeakerLabel to true, based on the source code.
I expect there is a Speaker key in the transcription result, but no.
